# Python program to find all video titles of a playilist

Tags: python, youtube

I want to quickly find titles of all videos of a playlist on youtube. Please tell me how to do it using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use snippet provided below to create a list of titles of videos in a playlist on youtube

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = # Enter playlist url here as string
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'pl-video yt-uix-tile'})
names = []
for title in result:
    names.append(title.get('data-title'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will share result after trying this solution.